# How does inline (x86) assembly affect the program flow?

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to understand how such snippets are invoked during run time:

```
__asm{
    PUSH ES
    MOV CX,0
    //... More x86 assembly
};
```

Won't tweaking the registers corrupt the program flow execution?

For example: If CX above holds some value, wouldn't this mean that this register value will no longer be valid?

Does the compiler take care of these dependencies or does the execution of the snippet happens under special circumstances?

On which compilers the usage of inline assembly is not transparent?

Comment: Try looking at the resulting assembly code of the whole function.

Comment: In such questions, telling us the compiler would be gorgeous. GCC (with extended assembly) handles this differently than, for instance, clang.

Comment: That rather depends on the compiler. Some compilers expect all registers to be preserved while some try to track the register usage of the code for you, and others require you to manually mark-up the clobbered registers. Inline-assembly is inherently compiler-specific so you'll have to read up on the rules in the compiler's manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## GCC

In **GCC** you **have to specify** the affected registers explicitly to prevent corruption of the exectution flow:

```
asm [volatile] ( AssemblerTemplate
                  : OutputOperands
                  [ : InputOperands
                  [ : Clobbers ] ])
```

> While the compiler is aware of changes to entries listed in the output
> operands, the inline asm code may modify more than just the
> outputs.[...] calculations may require additional registers, [...]
> list them in the clobber list.

Please use the **"memory"** clobber argument if your code performs reads or writes to other items, than already listed.

> The "memory" clobber tells the compiler that the assembly code
> performs memory reads or writes to items other than those listed in
> the input and output operands

*Reference*: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

## MSVC

In **MSVC** on the other hand, you **don't need to preserve** the general purpose registers:

> When using __asm to write assembly language in C/C++ functions, you
> don't need to preserve the EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, or EDI registers. [...]
>
> You should preserve other registers you use (such as DS, SS, SP, BP,
> and flags registers) for the scope of the __asm block. You should
> preserve the ESP and EBP registers unless you have some reason to
> change them.

*Reference:* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a8ss06.aspx

---

**EDITS**: changed *should* to *have to* for gcc and added note about the "memory" clobber argument, follwing Olafs suggestions.

Comment: Actually you **have to** spcify clobbered registers and even memory. This is not optional.

Comment: @Olaf: I agree :). Adapted the answer.

Comment: I mentioned memory intentionally, too. Without this listed, gcc might hold values from memory variables, e.g. arrays/structs/etc. in nont clobbered registers, thus your assembler code might access outdated data when reading them. This is the reason you can use `asm volatile { "" :::"memory" }` as a compiler barrier.

Answer (score 1):

There are some additional flags that can be passed to the inline assembly code. One of them is the "clobber list", that indicates to the C/C++ compiler the list of registers that will be modified by the bloc of assembly code.

Note that the way to specify these additional flags is dependent on the compiler (it is completely different in Microsoft Visual C++, GCC etc...)

For GCC, see for instance:

https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3

Comment: He's asking explicitly about (Microsoft) Visual C++.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Latest edit has added GCC to the tags as well.

Comment: Inline-assembler is implementation-specific. As written, your answer invokes the impressing there is one common syntax/semantics. Please edit.